# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0. on Postgres

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am trying to connect my **postgres** db with **Entity Framework**.
here is my code:
app.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
    </providers>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework6.Npgsql" />
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    assembly binding here...
  </runtime>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
      <add name="Npgsql Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Entities" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=userdb;Userid=userid;Password=mypass;Protocol=3;Pooling=true;MinPoolSize=1;MaxPoolSize=20;ConnectionLifeTime=15" providerName="Npgsql" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

dbcontext file:

```
public class AuthenticationTestContext : DbContext
    {

        public AuthenticationTestContext() : base(nameOrConnectionString: "Entities")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Tbluser> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Tblrole> Roles { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("authtest");
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

I am using below packages: 
*EntityFramework6.Npgsql v6.4.1*
*EntityFramework v6.4.0*
*Npgsql v4.1.3*

Now I am stuck to establish the connection.
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0. error shows.

Comment: see the stack trace: 
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)

Comment: at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder.cs:line 65
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.GetPoolAndSettings() in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnection.cs:line 144
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) in C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnection.cs:line 328
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString) in

Comment: C:\projects\npgsql\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnection.cs:line 113
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String nameOrConnectionString)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ProviderName()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DefaultModelCacheKeyFactory.Create(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()

Comment: at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at AuthenticationTest.Core.Services.LoginService.GetUser() in F:\...\Services\LoginService.cs:line 22